# Modification of build events and project dependencies programmatically

Tags: c#

In my project, I use a template wizard to include projects from project templates. I also need to programmatically set the project dependencies and build actions programmatically. How can I do the same (at runtime) without directly modifying the csproj file?

Comment: Why do you not want to just directly modify the .csproj file?

Comment: anyone has any idea where the .proj files are at runtime, i have never heard of such a thing

Comment: My project instantiates a new instance of VS2010 IDE and provides the user with a ready-to-build solution with several projects added from project templates at runtime. Modification of the csproj file will result in changes only if the project is reloaded. That is not a commendable solution.